# WebsocketServer: send message on event to connected client

Tags: go, websocket

Problem is simple: i have WS server that doing it's "for {}". I need "register" connected user, then send message on event(outside of CoreWS function). I'm added NodeJS example that doing exactly what i need, for better understanding.

Go Lang Code that fails:
i'm using this pkg https://github.com/gobwas/ws

```
var conn_itf interface{} //yeah,
var op_itf interface{} //i know it's not how it works

func main() {
    go collector()
    go sender()
    http.ListenAndServe(":3333", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        conn, _, _, err := ws.UpgradeHTTP(r, w)
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
        go func() {
            defer conn.Close()

            for {
                msg, op, err := wsutil.ReadClientData(conn)
                conn_itf = conn // i'm trying to "register" user
                op_itf = op
                if err != nil {

                }
                err = wsutil.WriteServerMessage(conn, op, msg)
                if err != nil {

                }
            }
        }()
    }))
}

func collector() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("conn: ", conn_itf)
        fmt.Println("op: ", op_itf)
        time.Sleep(10000 * time.Millisecond)
    }
}

func sender() {
    for {
        msg := []byte("Hello world!")
        time.Sleep(50000 * time.Millisecond)
        wsutil.WriteServerMessage(conn_itf, op_itf, msg)  //invoking ws-send
    }
}
```

NodeJS that working:

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3333 })
wss.on('connection', ws => {
    sockets.set('key', ws) //this code remember active connection
    ws.on('message', message => {
      console.log(`Received message => ${message}`)
    })

})


function callsend(data) {
    const ws = sockets.get('key') //this code sending message on invoking
    ws.send(data)
}
```

Comment: I personally like https://github.com/gorilla/websocket better. I use it in my game server: https://github.com/hewiefreeman/GopherGameServer

Comment: @hueyfreeman gorilla ws probbably a bit more popular and common, but it's probably got same problem with Io.Writer and OpConn. The direct problem is to store them, and i don't know how to do it exactly.

Comment: What do you mean by store them? In memory? The socket connection `conn` is right there for you to use in your endless for-loop (that you should be `break`ing out of on error). You shouldn't ever need to touch any of the readers/writers yourself.

Comment: @hueyfreeman i'm need exactly as Example in NodeJS. Probably to use variable that will send message or channel will be easyer, but my goal is learning.